# .NET CORE Serial Class not reading data past 4KBytes in BaseStream or ReadBuffer when published to Linux machine using tty ports

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, serial-port, embedded

I built a serial port file transfer .NET CORE 3.0 application that works fine in windows, but can only read small amounts of data on linux. Basically I'm transmitting data from one machine and the receiving machine reads data like this:

```
        _serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 7000000;
...more setup code 

        Console.WriteLine("Serial receiver started at " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " Collecting and decoding file data for 4 minute intervals. Please wait...");
        Console.WriteLine("Header search pattern: " + BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(header)));
        int sleepTimeMiliseconds = (240000 - (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < 1) ? 0 : 240000 - (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeMiliseconds); // wait for about 4 minutes for the data to come in.
        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize];

        //read data then discard buffer to get new data from the transmitting machine
        if (!_serialPort.IsOpen) // serial port could close when operating system sleeps
            _serialPort.Open();
        _serialPort.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
        //HundredKBBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
        _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        stopwatch.Restart();
        Console.WriteLine("Data buffer size in bytes: " + dataBuffer.Length);
        DecodeFileData(dataBuffer, header, trailer);
```

I've also tried using `_serialPort.BaseStream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);` rather than `_serialPort.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);` but the same issue happens. I have never seen any bytes past 4096 in the buffer, so I'm not sure how to make this happen in a linux environment. Is the buffer size smaller and not changeable? I have used `_serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 7000000;` but it doesn't seem to help the issue. The linux machine is either CentOS or Redhat

Comment: The serial port on Linux still seems to be buggy. Your problem may add to it. [SerialPort for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#serialport-for-linux), [GitHub issue #33146](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33146)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4KBytes is a limitation of tty buffers. The kernel has an internal buffer of 4096 bytes. If this buffer is full and new a byte arrives on the serial port, the oldest byte in the buffer will be overwritten and thus will be lost.

I got around this problem of .NET CORE 3.0 not allowing me to set the _serialPort.ReadBufferSize by basically using a "stream byte reader" approach and incrementing my current index along my custom byte[] buffer by however many bytes were read in my previous read operation (polling to populate my custom buffer).

```
                    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[3000000]; // big enough buffer
                    bool singleReadIterationFinished = false;
                    while (!singleReadIterationFinished)
                    {
                        Task<int> bytesReadFromPort = _serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(dataBuffer, bufferOffset, dataBuffer.Length - bufferOffset); // read as many bytes as available at a time

                        //other code can go here since the thread isn't blocked 

                        bufferOffset += bytesReadFromPort.Result; // From docs.Microsoft: Calling the result properties get accessor will block the calling thread until the asyncrhonous operation is complete; this is equivalent to calling 'Wait' method.
                        if (bufferOffset > 2000000) // wait for 2megabytes of data. change this to megabytes. 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Read a total of : " + bufferOffset + " Bytes");
                            byte[] copyBuffer = new byte[dataBuffer.Length];
                            Array.Copy(dataBuffer, 0, copyBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
                            DecodeFileData(copyBuffer, header, trailer); // need to call this asyncronously
                            singleReadIterationFinished = true;
                        }
                    }
```